# Choose an Application

Tags: startup-applications

When I try to install an application from the Ubuntu Software Center or Internet, I keep getting a screen called "Launch Application", which says:
"This link needs to be opened with an application. Send to:
Choose an Application. As a newcomer to Ubuntu and just a user (not an IT expert), I don't know what to choose. Please help.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual-boot Acer XP laptop.

Comment: Try to install app from terminal using `sudo apt-get install <appname>` and post the error here.

Comment: Install an application from the Software Center? Are you clicking on the install button or how are you doing it?

Comment: I've tried installing from the terminal, but it keeps demanding my password, which I assume is my ubuntu password, but won't let me input it.

Comment: If I try from the software center, I get the choose application screen.

Comment: The applications I've been trying to download are Adobe flash, Adobe reader and Google Chrome. I get the same problems each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Reader:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/install-adobe-reader-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/

As for google chrome, or "Chromium" I suggest trying it like you probably already have before from the terminal;


 ***Sudo apt-get install chromium***


 When it asks for your password it will say the username of the account which the expected password belongs.

***Note: Your password will not be displayed as you type.***

However it will be received by the terminal. 

As for Flash, and hopefully to fix the initial problem, Try this;

 **From The Terminal** 

***Sudo apt-get purge software-center***


Then,..


***Sudo apt-get install software-center***

 That will remove and re-install the software center hopefully sorting out any issues its having. Then procede to search for "Flash Player" and I'm sure you get it from there... Anyway I'm new at all this also so I know how frustrating it can be. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I was finallly able to ger it to accept my password and to purge and reinstall the software center. When trying to get and install chromium. I got a message that it had been replaced by chromium-bsu. I installed that, but can't find it. I'm beginning to feel very stupid.

Comment: To find Chromiu just goto the dash logo on the launcher and type the letter C it'll show up. Also if you found my answer helpful please mark it as having answered your question. That way time can be spent on unanswered questions.

Comment: I found it, but unfortunately it turned out to be a game.

Comment: I've managed to sort out my Chrome problem, which I had downloaded before something when wrong with my ubunt, resulting in my no longer being able to find it. @Bellini, Your tip for me to go to the dash board helped and I was able to find it again.

Comment: Thanx, and BTW if you found the info helpfull please don't hesitate to mark my answer as accepted for your question to let everyone know that it's sorted out now. >:)